# Is "Retinal Glial Cells Enhance Human Vision Acuity" creationist propaganda?

Tags: visual-system

The paper [Retinal Glial Cells Enhance Human Vision Acuity](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/44610879_Retinal_Glial_Cells_Enhance_Human_Vision_Acuity) is profusely quoted by creationists as "proof" of the "perfect design" of the human eye.

The paper is about *biology* but [published in Physical Review Letters](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.104.158102) (open access, click PDF). Is it generally accepted as legitimate science, though cited by creationists, or is it thinly veiled creationist propaganda?

Comment: I've adjusted the wording of your question to avoid overtly soliciting opinions. In Biology SE we should ask questions that can have fact-based answers. The classic example of the debunking of intelligent design arguments is the flagella motor, looking for a source for that now... Here's one https://youtu.be/jdF-ugdl4mc but just search "flagella motor intelligent design debunked" for more.

Comment: @uhoh, thanks. This is my first question here.

Comment: apparently these are harder: [Determine if a coincident point in a pair of rotated hexagonal lattices is closest to the origin](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3705547/284619) and [Can there be an energetically unbounded three-body orbit where escape is impossible due to conservation of angular momentum?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3657498/284619) which reminds me that I need to [post it in MO](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/4582)